# When $\vec Q(\vec r) = -i\vec k \times \vec A = 0$?

Tags: vector-spaces, vectors

> I have an equation $\vec Q(\vec r) = -i\vec k \times \vec F$, where i
>   is an imaginary number and $\vec k, \vec A$ are some vectors. I need
>   to find $\vec k$ such that $\vec Q(\vec r) = 0$ so $\vec k \times \vec
> F = 0$.

$\vec F(\vec r) = \vec A e^{i(\vec k \vec r-\omega t)}$

I have rewritten it as $(F_zk_y - F_yk_z, F_xk_z - F_zk_x, F_yk_x-F_xk_y) = (0,0,0)$, so I got three equations.

$(F_zk_y - F_yk_z, F_xk_z - F_zk_x, F_yk_x-F_xk_y) = (A_zk_y - A_yk_z, A_xk_z - A_zk_x, A_yk_x-A_xk_y)e^{i(\vec k \vec r - \omega t)}$

It's probably trivial but I got $1 = 1$. Is it wrong or does it mean that for any $\vec k$ is $\vec Q(\vec r) = 0$? It feels strange.

Comment: It doesn't look like $\overrightarrow{Q}$ depends on $\overrightarrow{r}$ at all...

Comment: Maybe I wrote it badly, I will edit it.

Comment: Aside from @kccu 's comment, remember that $\| \vec{k} \times \vec{F} \| = \| \vec{k} \| \cdot \|\vec{F} \| \cdot \sin(\theta)$. Try making $\vec{k}$ and $\vec{F}$ parallel.

Comment: Also you have computed the cross product incorrectly. Check the first term.

Comment: It's just a typo.

Comment: In your formula for $\overrightarrow{F}$, should the $\overrightarrow{k}\overrightarrow{r}$ be $\overrightarrow{k}\cdot\overrightarrow{r}$?

Comment: Yes, it's  a scalar multiplication.

Comment: In any case, you should use Harry's comment. You have $\|\overrightarrow{F}\|=\|\overrightarrow{A}\|$ (since $|e^{ia}|=1$ for any $a$). So as long as $\overrightarrow{A}$ and $\overrightarrow{k}$ are nonzero, the only time you get $\overrightarrow{0}$ for their cross product is when they are parallel. The directions of $\overrightarrow{k}$ and $\overrightarrow{A}$ do not depend on $\overrightarrow{r}$, so they are either always parallel or never parallel.

Comment: So is it true that $\vec k$ can be arbitrary?

Comment: Or if $\vec k$ is a multiplication of $\vec A$? So those two vectors are linearly dependent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need to realize is that for any two non-zero  $3$-vectors $A$ and $B$,

$A \times B = 0 \Leftrightarrow A = cB \tag{1}$

for some scalar $c$.  This follows easily from the 
definition of $A \times B$; indeed, writing

$A = A_x \mathbb i + A_y \mathbb j + A_z \mathbb k, \tag{2}$

$B = B_x \mathbb i + B_y \mathbb j + B_z \mathbb k, \tag{3}$

we have

$A \times B = (A_y B_z - A_z B_y) \mathbb i + (A_z B_x - A_x B_z) \mathbb j + (A_x B_y - A_y B_x) \mathbb k; \tag{4}$

thus, if $A \times B = 0$,

$A_y B_z - A_z B_y = A_z B_x - A_x B_z = A_x B_y - A_y B_x = 0; \tag{5}$

assuming

$B_x, B_y, B_z \ne 0, \tag{6}$

which can always be arranged by a suitable choice of Cartesian vector basis on $\Bbb R^3$ (a fact I leave to my readers to verify for themselves), (5) gives rise to the ratio equations

$\dfrac{A_y}{B_y} = \dfrac{A_z}{B_z}, \tag{7}$

$\dfrac{A_x}{B_x} = \dfrac{A_z}{B_z}, \tag{8}$

and

$\dfrac{A_x}{B_x} = \dfrac{A_y}{B_y}. \tag{9}$

Combining any two of (7)-(9) yields

$\dfrac{A_x}{B_x} = \dfrac{A_y}{B_y} = \dfrac{A_z}{B_z}; \tag{10}$

denoting the common ratio occurring in (10) by $c$, we see that

$A_x = cB_x, A_y = cB_y, A_z = cB_z, \tag{11}$

or

$A = cB. \tag{12}$

Going the other way is even easier; starting from (12),

$A \times B = A \times cA = cA \times A = 0.  \tag{13}$

(1) may be had even more quickly provided we accept the standard $3$-vector identity

$X \times (Y \times Z) = (X \cdot Z) Y - (X \cdot Y) Z; \tag{14}$

with $A \times B = 0$ we have by (14)

$(B \cdot B)A - (B \cdot A) B = B \times (A \times B) = 0; \tag{15}$

since $B \ne 0$ implies $B \cdot B \ne 0$, (15) may be written

$A = \dfrac{A \cdot B}{B \cdot B}B; \tag{16}$

taking

$c = \dfrac{A \cdot B}{B \cdot B} \tag{17}$

yields (12).

Applying these considerations to the problem at hand indicates we must take
$\vec k$ to be a scalar multiple of $\vec F$ to achieve the desired result, and that any such multiple of $\vec F$ will suffice.  The factors of $i$ or 
$e^{i(\vec k \cdot \vec r - \omega t)}$ do not affect this conclusion.